# Point of intersection of two circles with center of one circle lying on another circle

Tags: circles, conic-sections

Consider the following configuration:
[image]

Two circles with center R and S are shown.Now, suppose I know point R and S and let the radius of both circles be $r_1$ and $r_2$. I need to find point V and U.
I know that one way is to solve the equations of both circle and finally getting a quadratic equation and solving it.But sometimes it become too calculative.

Is there another simple approach using geometry and where algebra is minimised?

Comment: It's hard for me to understand the question. Do you mean that knowing distances $r_1$ and $r_2$, the construction done by ruler and compasses of $R$ and $S$ should obtained by ruler only ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I want to find coordinates of point U and V given that I know the value of $r_1$ and $r_2$. I don't have to use any ruler or compass. Just geometric approach or simpler algebric  approach.

Comment: If S is the origin and R lies on x-axis, it requires only simple algebraic calculation. Isn't it possible for you?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be the midpoint of $UV$.
Let $x=RZ,y=ZS$.
By Pythagoras, $r_1^2-r_2^2=x^2-y^2$, and also $x+y=r_1$.
Find $x-y$, then $x$ and $y$.

Comment: But how to find coordinate of point U and V?

Comment: First,$ZU^2=r_1^2-x^2$.  Let that length $ZU$ be $z$.  Then, a vector perpendicular to $(a,b)$ is $(b,-a)$.  Take the vector $RZ$, divide by $x$, multiply by $z$ and take its perpendicular, to get the vector $ZU$